# Succinctly evaluating an object with MULTIPLE class checks with isKindOfClass

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a better way to see if an object has one of several classes than

```
if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] || [item isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] || 
[item isKindOfClass:[NSPredicate class]] || [item isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]] 
|| [item isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
   return YES;
};
```

Is there a more graceful way than this? Preferably an inline way that doesn't require creating categories or multiline for loops/arrays.

Comment: Yuk.  I guess it depends on what you are trying to accomplish, but it seems like there is improvement for a better design maybe. Does 'item' need to call some method all those classes have in common? Maybe respondsToSelector: would be more efficient.

Comment: Using respondsToSelector means that all of the classes your testing against will conveniently share a selector that no other class does. Otherwise you'll get a false positive.

Comment: This definitely calls for some design improvement. My first idea would be to tag all the classes by a protocol via a category and then check just for the protocol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
NSArray *classes = @[ [NSArray class], [NSNumber class], [NSPredicate class], (etc.)];
for (Class cls in classes) {
    if ([item isKindOfClass:cls]) {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

It's not significantly more succinct, but I think it's easier to read and maintain.

**Edit** : Naturally, you would add a stipulation about no loops or arrays right as I'm writing this up. :)

You might be able to do it with an NSPredicate and an "@any.FUNCTION(isKindOfClass:)" keypath, but I don't think it would be any more graceful; most people would just find it harder to read. I really think an array and a for loop is the way to go here.

Comment: That is good...can you put think of a way to to this inline with only the if statement (in other words, without the `for` loop)?

Comment: great, this is the best practical approach, until we get something like `isKindOfClasses` , in future :-)

Comment: @MicRO moving this code to a method to an NSObject category method called isKindOfClasses: and replacing the classes array with an argument would be a nice way of moving it away. it would also take the for loop away from the OPs code

Comment: @wattson12 That's great, but don't catagories complicate things by adding dependencies to a project that you plan on sharing as a library?

Comment: @wattson12 yeah, that too sounds fine, please feel free to post answers if you find further better solutions. (as you know well that looping is not at a desired practice )

Comment: @MicRO I'm just trying to avoid a bird's nest of loops and conditionals. I'm not claiming that looping is inherently wrong...

Comment: i don't think theres a need for a new answer, it would just be repeating BJs anyway. @yourfriendzak i don't think you should be worried about adding categories, if i was sharing code i would be more concerned about readability (assuming its open source) than adding extra files

Comment: @wattson12 Thank you. Check out my answer below and tell me what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
NSArray *classes = @[ [NSArray class], [NSDictionary class], [NSSet class] ];
NSUInteger *matches = [classes indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id class, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
           return [item isKindOfClass:class]);
       }].count;
```

Comment: Now that I think about it, this is terrible. It's much less readable even though its fewer lines.